# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 removed my php7.0-fpm?

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, wordpress, upgrade

Upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 went fine. Nginx was 1.9.14 on both version, then when I upgrade the server to 18.04 nginx changed to 1.14.0 which would be fine if the upgrade didn't delete the binary file for php7.0, my symfony (integrated with wordpres) site worked with php7.0-fpm and now I get a 502.

Is there a way to install just the binary for php7.0 or changed the configuration to use the new php7.2? Which approach is the best?

Comment: The old php -v was PHP 7.0.5, now it 7.2.24. Is there a way to donwgrade php?

Comment: You just have to set the socket path in your nginx config, to point to the 7.2 path.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading should be avoided and only used if your aplication is not ready for the new version (yet).

In your nginx configuration there has to be a reference to php7.0-fpm - just change that to use php7.2-fpm...